# Strtok inside a for statement

Tags: c

```
    char inputp1[132], inputp2[132], inputp3[132], inputp4[132], inputp5[132];

    char input[MAX_NAME_SZ];
    printf("-> ");
    fgets (input, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin); // user input
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;

    int count=0,i,len; //counting

    len = strlen(input); 
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++) 
        {  
       if(input[i]==' ') 
          count++;
        }

    printf("the number of words are: %d\n",count + 1);


    strcpy(inputp1, strtok(input , " ,-"));
    for (count = count; count < 0; count-- )
    {
    strcpy(inputp2, strtok(NULL, " ,-"));
    }
```

Okay so I have user input and im making it so that at every single ,- or space it will make a token.

What im wondering is is their a way to make a for statment so that for every single string after a space it will run

```
strcpy(inputp2, strtok(NULL, " ,-"));
```

Also I would like it to count up for every single time so that the first time it ran the for function it would do

`strcpy(inputp2, strtok(NULL, " ,-"));`

and the second time

`strcpy(inputp3, strtok(NULL, " ,-"));`

ect.

Ex: I input 10 20 30

input and inputp1 come out as 10

inputp2 comes out as 20

inputp3 comes out as 30

Comment: `count < 0` --> `count >= 0` ?, `char inputp1[132], inputp2[132], inputp3[132], inputp4[132], inputp5[132];` --> `char inputp[5][132];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you elaborate a little bit more than that?

Comment: `count < 0` : The contents of for-loop will not be executed.

Comment: `char inputp1[132], inputp2[132], inputp3[132], inputp4[132], inputp5[132];` : It uses an array.  E.g `i = 0;`... `strcpy(inputp[i++], strtok(input , " ,-"));` ... `strcpy(inputp[i++], strtok(NULL, " ,-"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are needing, you can use a single statically declared array to hold the input as well as each separated token. You can duplicate the first token in the first element (holding the original input string) by virtue of the modification to the string by `strtok` itself. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_NAME = 5, MAX_NAME_SZ = 132 };

int main (void) {

    size_t i, count = 0;
    char *delim = " .,-\t\n";
    char input[MAX_NAME][MAX_NAME_SZ] = { "" };
    char *p = NULL;

    if (!fgets (input[count++], MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (p = strtok (input[0], delim);
        p && count < MAX_NAME;
        p = strtok (NULL, delim), count++) {
        strcpy (input[count], p);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("input[%zu] : %s\n", i, input[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Since `strtok` adds a *nul-terminating* character in the original string after each token, `input[0]` is automatically terminated after the first token.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_input
10 20 30
input[0] : 10
input[1] : 10
input[2] : 20
input[3] : 30
```

If I didn't understand what you were attempting to accomplish, let me know, otherwise, let me know if you have any questions.